# Cant resize win forms TableLayoutPanel after project save or other changes

Tags: winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I am encountering an problem with `TableLayoutPanel`. I have configured that my size of table columns and rows are mostly dynamic, but the dynamic scaling isn't working after I have saved or done other changes(Can't say when exactly this problem started) and I am trying to resize the table borders. My configuration for my table is shown below:
[example1 http://dl.dropbox.com/s/4ayi073x6xfxokb/configuration.jpg](http://dl.dropbox.com/s/4ayi073x6xfxokb/configuration.jpg)

No change example(the white square is just photoediting..):

[example2 http://dl.dropbox.com/s/08zhm19264r3qzf/original.jpg](http://dl.dropbox.com/s/08zhm19264r3qzf/original.jpg)

With border resize example:

[example3 http://dl.dropbox.com/s/gelxjb8s2ip5bzj/after.jpg](http://dl.dropbox.com/s/gelxjb8s2ip5bzj/after.jpg)

Here it should have scaled accordingly to the resized borders, but it doesn't. I could not find an answer in google that was near to my situation, but what am I doing wrong, because the first time when i was creating and resizing the table, it was working perfectly as i wanted.

Added the designer.cs code for the  TableLayoutPanel:

```
    // 
    // tableLayoutPanel2
    // 
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.ColumnCount = 5;
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 50F));
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 25F));
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 25F));
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 25F));
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 25F));
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.buttonFirstClockSecondDay_Type_A, 3, 1);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.textBox1, 1, 0);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.textBox2, 2, 0);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.label5, 0, 1);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.label1, 0, 3);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.label6, 0, 5);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.label7, 0, 7);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.buttonFirstClockFirstDay_Type_A, 1, 1);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.buttonFirstClockFirstDay_Type_B, 1, 2);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.buttonSecondClockFirstDay_Type_A, 1, 3);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.buttonSecondClockFirstDay_Type_B, 1, 4);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.buttonFirstClockSecondDay_Type_B, 3, 2);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.buttonSecondClockSecondDay_Type_A, 3, 3);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.buttonSecondClockSecondDay_Type_B, 3, 4);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.buttonThirdClockFirstDay_Type_A, 1, 5);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.buttonThirdClockFirstDay_Type_B, 1, 6);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.buttonFourthClockFirstDay_Type_A, 1, 7);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.buttonFourthClockFirstDay_Type_B, 1, 8);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.buttonThirdClockSecondDay_Type_A, 3, 5);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.buttonThirdClockSecondDay_Type_B, 3, 6);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.buttonFourthClockSecondDay_Type_A, 3, 7);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.buttonFourthClockSecondDay_Type_B, 3, 8);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.label3, 2, 1);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.label2, 2, 2);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.label8, 2, 3);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.label4, 2, 4);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.label14, 2, 5);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.label13, 2, 6);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.label15, 2, 7);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.label19, 2, 8);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.label10, 4, 1);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.label11, 4, 2);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.label9, 4, 3);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.label12, 4, 4);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.label17, 4, 5);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.label18, 4, 6);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.label16, 4, 7);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.label20, 4, 8);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(382, 56);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Name = "tableLayoutPanel2";
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.RowCount = 9;
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 25F));
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 12.5F));
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 12.5F));
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 12.5F));
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 12.5F));
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 12.5F));
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 12.5F));
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 12.5F));
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 12.5F));
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(437, 288);
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.TabIndex = 6;
    this.tableLayoutPanel2.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.tableLayoutPanel2_Paint);
```

Comment: A screenshot is always a lousy way to have to debug code.  Open the form's designer.cs source code file, paste the code you find there.

Comment: @HansPassant Are you sure you want that code? It is 915 lines long, anything specific maybe?

Comment: So users are expected to post a minimum repro.  Surely you don't need that many rows and columns to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: @HansPassant Added the part where the TableLayoutPanel is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason after reloading the solution it works again. It is a mystery why it did not work before..

Answer (score 1):

The first picture has **drag handles** which indicates it was taken at **design-time**.

The second picture does NOT have drag handles which means it was taken at run-time?  Did you change the size of the FORM?

To make the TableLayoutPanel change size with the Form you need to either:

1. Use the Anchor() property of the TableLayoutPanel and turn ON all
   four sides.
2. Set the Dock() property of the TableLayoutPanel to Fill.

Which is a better approach depends on your overall Form layout, which we cannot see.

Comment: No it was also at design-time. Sadly i forgot to click back on the form.